# Querying Mongo Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to perform a query on the following entry in my mongo database:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("597b19512a5b1c3258e6440e"),
    "fdata" : [
            {
                    "type" : "header",
                    "subtype" : "h1",
                    "label" : "Date Of Commencement"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "paragraph",
                    "subtype" : "p",
                    "label" : "The partnership business shall be deemed to have commenced on and from :"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "date",
                    "label" : "Date Field",
                    "description" : "Enter correct date as per instructions in the clause",
                    "className" : "form-control",
                    "name" : "date-1501239537753"
            },
            {
                    "type" : "button",
                    "subtype" : "submit",
                    "label" : "Next",
                    "className" : "btn btn-primary",
                    "name" : "button-1501239595350",
                    "style" : "primary"
            }
    ]
}
```

I have to fetch the entire array called **fdata** and the parameter available to me is the value of **label** in an array called **cl** as so:

```
cl = ['Date Of Commencement'];
```

My question is how do I access that array entry as the following code gives me a 'unexpected token'

My query is like this:(using NodeJS in the backend)

```
    for(var i=0; i<cl.length ;i++) {

        var dummy = cl[i];

        //console.log(dummy);

        result[i] = db.collection('clauses').findOne({fdata[0].label: dummy},{fdata});
    }
```

Its in a loop because in most cases the array **cl** will have multiple entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The findOne query you're using is asynchronous. This is why you see `[ Promise { <pending> } ]`. 
There are a lot of approaches to handle asynchronous behavior:

- callbacks
- async library
- Promises
- generators + coroutines
- async + await

If your Nodejs version is new enough (8+) it should support async/await approach.

```
async function doJob(arr) {
  const clauses = db.collection('clauses');

  for (const key of arr) {
    const result = await clauses.findOne({'fdata.label': key});
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: That printed [ Promise { <pending> } ] on the console. I am not sure what it means and the await keyword is new to me as well. I do not have much knowledge about the MEAN stack I am still learning. Could you kindly expand your answer a bit.